# Confusion about @3x designation for images

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage

In my app, I've generated some @3x images to be used which I'd like to use for the iPhone6+, 6, 5, and 5s. This works fine on iOS8, but when I'm testing on an iPhone5s with iOS7.1, it doesn't recognize @3x so the images don't appear.

What approach should I take here? The @3x images are all measured correctly, if I just name them @2x will that have the same effect since the iPhone 6+ will figure out what to do with it?

Comment: @3x images are only for the iPhone 6+.

Comment: @rmaddy I know, but to keep my bundle size down I reuse a lot of my images. If I rename all my 3x files to 2x, will it make any difference on my iPhone6+?

Comment: Sure, the @2x images will look pixelated (slightly) on the iPhone 6+ since they will be scaled.

Comment: @rmaddy I wrote my understanding of the situation as an answer, I think that's what you're trying to say? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not a simple matter of renaming from 3x to 2x. If the 1x image is say 24x48 then the 2x needs to be 48x96 and the 3x needs to be 72x120. If you renamed the 72x120 3x image to 2x then iOS will think the image is 36x60 points instead of 24x48 points. It will be all wrong.

Comment: @rmaddy What about if I only have a 3x, and an iPad wants an 2x, will it grab the 3x and downsize it?

Comment: That I don't know. My apps have icons in all three sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot determine if you already using Xcode Asset Catalog. It's an asset management for different image size.

Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1

**Creating Asset Catalog**

1. If you existing projects and you don't have  file named Images.xcassets, add new file with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

**Adding files**

2. Drag drop the files on the editor **OR** use the "+" icon at the bottom of the editor. Notice the option for `1x`, `2x`, `3x` is already there.

[image]

**Using the images**

3. The image is accessible via its name. For example: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_info"];`. It will use whichever size accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. This is what solved my situation. Maybe you can add this also, but I had to change all my 3x images to 2x (if I already didn't have a 2x) so that it would work on iOS7 and below. If you already do have a 3x and 2x and 1x for an image, then it will work fine for all iOS's and devices. But again, I was reusing a lot of images to save space in my binary.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put all images like @1x, @2x, @3x and Retina 4 @2x to work with all devices.

Apple provides document for all images and its use.

Check iOS Human Interface Guidelines : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

[image]

For Example :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this, but in my situation I'm reusing iPad 2x to work for my iPhone6+ 3x so it's a bit confusing. But I think asset catalogs are the way to go.